# can't get datatables work with a django generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I am trying to use datatables in a django application. 
Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> My  web application </title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "./DataTables-1.9.0/media/css/demo_table.css";
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./DataTables-1.9.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').dataTable();
    } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
    {% if success %}
        <form action="." method="POST">
        {{ my_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
        <br>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead> <tr>
    {%for x in htl%}
        <th> {{x}} </th>
    {% endfor%}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for x in mytable %}
        <tr>
        {% for y in x %}
            <td> {{y}} </td>
        {%endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor%}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
        <form action="." method="POST">
        {{ my_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass a python list with each row as an item in the list and format the table in the template.html as is seen from the code. I couldn't get datatables working at all. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Just a quick guess, but i would say the style import has to occur before you load the javascript.

Comment: I moved the style import to above the javascript but nothing changed, thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your HTML might be bad:

```
<thead> <tr>
{%for x in htl%}
    <th> {{x}} </th>
{% endfor%}
</th>
</thead>
```

That second `</th>` should be `</tr>`

Also, you may want to check out this: https://github.com/eire1130/Django_datatables

It's a wrapper I wrote to simplify embedding datatables into django templates.

Also, i notice you are using {% block %}, but I don't see what you are extending?

Edit for configuring media and static files:

At the very top of your settings.py add these lines:

```
import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

(you should do this in all of your projects, doing this will save you a lot of headaches in the future)

Also, in your settings.py you should go down to about midway through the file and look four lines (really two, but we will also do static at the same time)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

The above will set up your media files in a director like myproject/media where your app is located at myproject/myapp

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/'
```

The above will set up your static files in a directory like myproject/static where your app is located at myproject/myapp.

In the same directory where settings.py is located, create a file called "urls.py" if your old urls.py is already here, move it to your app folder, so your old urls.py should be located at myproject/myapp/urls.py.

Your new urls.py should be located at myproject/urls.py

In this new and totally blank python file, add these lines:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),
    (r'^', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
```

)

Please note the "include" at the very bottom. Obviously, you will need to change this to reflect your project and app names.

Now that this is setup, you will need to create a media folder that resides at myproject/media. You should do the same for /static while your at it.

In this directory, you should place any media files you care about. For example, I have a folder called "plugins", in there is datatables. The path looks like this: myproject/media/plugins/datables, and then in there are all the datatables files.

Now, in your template, point the link to the directory:

```
'/media/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
```

Notice there is no "." at the beginning, and no @include. Just the url.

This should setup datatables for you and allow to serve media at the same time. In a production environment, you wouldn't do it exactly like this, but for prototyping and learning, this will work fine

Comment: The usage of {% block %} does not necessarily mean he is extending another template. The shown template could also be the basetemplate, and the block-tags are there to be able to override these parts from a childtemplate.

Comment: @marue I know, I was just wondering if he showed us a code snippet, or if there was information missing.

Comment: I made the two changes mentioned in the comments </th> to </tr> (thanks for the catch)  , Ialso moved the style import to above the javascript code. Updated code is replaced the old one in the question, still not working though. I looked at the Django_datatables and tried to use the load_once example but I can;t seem to get it to work with my application, thanks for the help.

Comment: @biomed without using datatables, is the HTML table rendering as expected (just take out the javascript call to datatables)?

Comment: Yes the html table is rendering as expected. I also tried the example on http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works and it works too. $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 }); : One thing I didn't mention is I am trying this using django development server, would it make any difference? I didn't think so as javascript is clientside but I am very new to these web technologies as you can tell so I may be wrong.

Comment: @biomed In that case, are you using firebug? Are there any errors getting thrown in developer console?

Comment: @biomed If I had to make a guess at this point, pending my above question, datatables isn't getting installed on the client machine properly. A very simple way to test, is to right click and "view page source" or similar. Look for the hyper link up top that leads to datatables and click it. If you get a page not found, you know where the problem resides. If this is the case, I'll ammend my answer to the best I can

Comment: @biomed i just saw your edit, using django developer server makes no difference. It will serve javascript and other media just fine.

Comment: Ok, I moved the datatables directory to my document root and I can open the hyperlink as you suggested but firebug gives me {$("#table_id").dataTable is not a function
http://localhost:8080/myapp/
Line 17}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9785/discussion-between-biomed-and-james-r)

Comment: @biomed Have you come to a solution? If so I would like to know it, as I am trying to use django-datables too.